# document.getElementById innerHTML not displaying

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

This should be a pretty easy thing to do, but it's not returning anything.
The function love() should kick off, getting a simple number prompt, and spitting out a list of a few items that uses that starting number.
the alert box correctly displays what I expect, but I want it to display on the screen.
(this is but a small section of what I'm after, but it's the kernel of it). No text is displaying in the IE, FF, or Chrome...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function love()
        {
            var ncxElement="";
            var idNumber = prompt("Enter beginning number","");
            var myText=document.getElementById("here");
            for (var i=1;i<5;i++)
            {
                ncxElement+=("<navPoint class=\"other\" id=\"page_"+idNumber+"\">\n");
                idNumber++;
            }
                alert(ncxElement);
                myText.innerHTML=ncxElement;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="love()">
    <p id="here">Begin!</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: where is your closing `</navPoint>` tag?

Comment: the ncxElement can be anything, the problem is that nothing displays on screen with the myText.innerHTML statement. I don't think the content of the output matters...?

Comment: You will not see anything in the browser, because there is no text in your `ncxElement`... Write some text into it and close the tags, then you will see the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display HTML on your page (without it being parsed), use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` and wrap it in a `<pre>` (to preserve the line breaks).

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Change:

```js
myText.innerHTML=ncxElement;
```

To:

```js
myText.textContent=ncxElement;
```

Change:

```html
<p id="here">Begin!</p>
```

To:

```html
<pre id="here">Begin!</pre>
```

Comment: I actually WANT the <navPoint class="other" id=" to display. I'm using this to automate some XML creation.

Comment: Getting closer with the <pre> idea. I tried    myText.innerHTML="<pre>"+ncxElement+"</pre>"; but that still doesn't display the actual XML code <navPoint yada yada ></navPoint>

Comment: @DonG Check out my latest updates and demo. It's displaying the XML fine.

Comment: Your JSFiddle is what I'm after! Yes, I'm trying to construct a large XML structure that takes a number of beginning numbers and increments them based on starting values. I think that puts me on the road to where I need to go! thanks very much TS.

Comment: and the .textContent property is new to me, that helped also, I bet. :-)

Answer (score 1):

navPoints are not valid html elements, so the browser doesn't know what to do with them. They are being added to the DOM, just not displayed unless you add styling to do so.

If you replace them with paragraph tags, it works fine. See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tzSXE/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function love()
    {
        var ncxElement="";
        var idNumber = prompt("Enter beginning number","");
        var myText=document.getElementById("here");
        for (var i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
ncxElement+=("<p class=\"other\" id=\"page_"+idNumber+"\">"+idNumber+ "</p>");
            idNumber++;
        }
            alert(ncxElement);
            myText.innerHTML=ncxElement;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="love()">
<p id="here">Begin!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I didn't think about the conflict that <navPoint> would create. Putting them in a <pre> container is what let them display correctly. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Your function just wraps elements inside another. There is no text inside or outside these elements to dipslay.
Try inserting some random text before closing tags to see the result.
Btw, the elements are successfully placed in the p tag.